# Does heroku support Express 3.0?

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I'm trying to deploy a node.js application to heroku, and get an error:

```
Installing dependencies with npm
       npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: express@'>=3.0.0'
```

When deploying from Cloud9. Does heroku support express 3.0?

Comment: Express 3 works fine with node 0.8.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably haven't specified what version of Nodejs your app supports.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-versions

By default, it uses Node 0.4.7, which will not work with express 3.x. I think you will need at least Node >= 0.5.0.

Comment: Thanks! This gets me running, but "breaks" everyauth. Any idea how to get the everyauth that's compatible with express 3.x onto heroku (I use NPM from a git repository on my dev environment).

Comment: @pat What part of everyauth stopped working? Is it giving any useful errors?

Comment: everyauth is not defined. I had this in my dev environment and had to use an everyauth build from their git repository rather than what npm normally installs. I'm not sure how I do this from heroku... Guess it's time to read the fabulous manual unless anyone here jumps in...

Comment: Well the answer to the everyauth problem was pretty easy. I modified package.json to look like this and all is well:

        , "everyauth": "git://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth.git#express3"